# Is there any SEO issues with default CDN path

Tags: seo, cdn

I'm currently having some issues with the Digital Oceans Spaces CDN, I want to add a custom CNAME for my CDN but the way DO works is that we should use DO name servers if we want auto-renew SSL for those custom CNAME.

The issue here is my current domain is managed by OVH with their NS and we want to avoid migrating all of our configuration to DO.

My question is this, is there any SEO issues if I use the default CDN path provided by DO and not our custom CNAME ?

The other solution here is to buy a new domain on DO and only use it for CDN but the same kind of question appears ... is there any SEO issues if I use another domain for my CNAME path ?